# How do Gradle Uploads Really Work?

Tags: gradle

I'm having some real problems understanding how all the pieces in gradle to create and upload an artifact fit together.

My intention in this script is simple: I want to download a source tarball and possibly a bunch of dependencies, run a "build.sh" shellscript which will end up creating a binary tarball and have the gradle script publish it to an artifact repo.

The main idea is that I can use gradle's dependency management, maven artifact knowledge and build parallelization and avoidance to control the execution of the build scripts themselves, mainly to manage my set of third party binary dependencies...

The following script fails with a 400 error, I suspect it's because I'm not linking the artifact with the actual output file.

What's the right and proper way to go?

```groovy
apply plugin: 'maven'

version 'testarch-4.2'

repositories {
  maven {
    url "http://nexus/..."
  }
}

configurations {
  sourceArchive
  binaryArchive
}

dependencies {
  sourceArchive "org.gnu:bash:4.2:src@tgz"
}

task buildFromSource(type: Exec) {
  inputs.files configurations.sourceArchive.files
  outputs.file file("${project.name}-${project.version}.tgz")
  executable './build.sh'
  def myArgs = configurations.sourceArchive.files.path
  myArgs.add(0, outputs.files.asPath)
  args myArgs
}

artifacts {
  // Is this really the only way to transform a singleton collection
  // into the singleton?
  //   def outputFile
  //   buildFromSource.outputs.files.each { outputFile = it }
  // Nope: this is better magic:
  def outputFile = buildFromSource.outputs.files.singleFile
  println outputFile.path
  binaryArchive file: outputFile, name: 'bash'
  // binaryArchive file: file(buildFromSource.outputs.files.asPath), name: 'bash'
}

uploadArchives {
  configuration = configurations.binaryArchive
  repositories.mavenDeployer {
    repository(url: "http://nexus/..") {
      authentication(userName: "me", password: "secret!")
    }
    pom.groupId = 'org.gnu'
  }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn buildFromSource
```

The error I get is:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'binaryArchive'
   > Error deploying artifact 'org.gnu:bash:tgz': Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://nexus/.../org/gnu/bash/testarch-4.2/bash-testarch-4.2.tgz. Return code is: 400
```

Updated from comments, same error - trying to get access to the nexus logs for further debugging.

Error from Nexus is "missing entity", see: [Missing Request Entity response to a PUT to Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775793/missing-request-entity-response-to-a-put-to-nexus)

Comment: I so much want to like gradle, but it really makes me feel so stupid. The documentation almost assumes that you already understand all the pieces, or assumes that you just want to set up a cargo-cult. How can I actually know _all_ the properties an object can accept, or even better: understand how the objects are plumbed together?

Comment: Do you literally get a 400? Hard to say why that would be the case. I'd check the `--info` and `--debug` output, and also the Nexus logs. To know all the properties an object can accept, check the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html), which further links into the Javadoc/Groovydoc.

Comment: I added the error message I got...

Is this fundamentally the right way to do this, or am I missing something obvious? Is there no better way to connect the output of a task to an artifact?

Comment: I find the reference docs to be extremely unhelpful, as they do not list all the properties you can attach to some construct, and because the names of the methods do not map to the actual strings you use in the gradle script. How these map to each other is something one is expected to "just know".

Comment: Can you give some examples? I suggest to move this discussion over to http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: `file(buildFromSource.outputs.files.asPath)` looks suspicious. I'd throw in a `println` to see what it evaluates to. You probably want something like `buildFromSource.outputs.files.singleFile` instead. Checking the Nexus logs would probably lead to a similar conclusion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40403/discussion-between-christian-goetze-and-peter-niederwieser)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of my problem was I was testing with an empty file. Nexus doesn't like empty files. As soon as I put content in it, Nexus was happy and the code was working.