# Missing Request Entity response to a PUT to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm trying to emulate a maven artifact publish to my Nexus repository, in an attempt to understand why my gradle build is failing.

I try:

```
curl -u 'me:secret'\
     -X PUT\
     -T my-artifact\
     -H 'Content-Type: maven-artifact/3.0.4'\
  http://nexus/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
```

and I get:

```
<body>
  <h1>400 - Bad Request</h1>
  <p>Missing request entity</p>
</body>
```

What's the "missing entity"?

Comment: Relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733585/how-do-gradle-uploads-really-work

Answer (score 0):

A working example of a project that deploys to Nexus with Gradle is part of the [Nexus Book Examples](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples) project and steps to follow are in the [Nexus Evaluation Guide](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval.html).