# How can I get gradle to log the HTTP interactions with a remote repository?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I am trying to debug a failing gradle upload (see [How do Gradle Uploads Really Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733585/how-do-gradle-uploads-really-work)), and I would really like to see what the actual HTTP requests and the responses are.

Running gradle with --info, --debug or --stacktrace does not add any interesting information. I'm stuck with a simple "400".

I'm looking at the other end right now, but there I have trouble getting Nexus to log what it did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything better than `--debug`. For a 400, the server log is probably the most interesting.

Comment: I got "missing entity"... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775793/missing-request-entity-response-to-a-put-to-nexus

Comment: `--debug` prints all kinds of Gradle task management stuff, but exactly zero additional information about requests (in case of maven-publish, that is).